# How to block a string containing specific characters and of specific length.?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

How can I block the use of 5 continuous vowels(a,e,i,o,u) in a string and allow the use of only one hyphen(-)? 
It should not allow continuous vowels even if it's in upper case (AEIOU) and also in both upper and lower case in continuous form like AeiOU, aEIou,eeeee, AoEEU, uuuaa, iiiOU etc. It should not allow the use of 5 continuous vowels, no digits are allowed and no special characters are allowed except hyphen. 
Right now I am using something like this,

```
/^(?![Aa][Ee][Ii][Oo][Uu])[a-zA-z\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]‌*-[a-zA-z\u00BF-\u1F‌FF\u2C00-\uD7FF]*$/
```

its is blocking only the continuous vowels that are AEIOU, Aeiou, aeiou etc

Comment: Without examples, it is not quite clear, but perhaps, the https://regex101.com/r/rS2kRb/2 will help. Please check.

Comment: For example: aeiou, eeeee, aaaaa, AEIOU, AeIoU, AAAAA, EEEee, OOuuu all there are not permitted as 5 continuous vowels are there, whereas eeee(4 continuous vowels ), aeiu(4 continuous vowels), Aeiu(4 continuous vowels) are permitted. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Ok, check this one - https://regex101.com/r/rS2kRb/3

Comment: its working fine but the hyphens are not mandatory, its depends on the end user if he wants to insert hyphens in the string or not. But in the above example, the hyphens are mandatory, itherwise its working right.  @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: thanks, I made the change and got the solution

Comment: But there is one thing not clear - do you want to match an empty string?

Comment: ^(?!.*-.*-)(?!.*[AaEeIiOoUu]{5})[a-zA-Z\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF][a-zA-Z\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\-]*$

Comment: No, it can be much simpler. You do not need `(?!.*-.*-)` since your pattern only matches 1 hyphen.

Comment: I don't need validation for the empty string, that is taken care in the UI end, this validation was for the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!.*[AaEeIiOoUu]{5})[a-zA-Z\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]*(?:-[a-zA-Z\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iV0vzD/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*[AaEeIiOoUu]{5})` - no any 5 consecutive vowels anywhere inside the string
- `[a-zA-Z\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]*` - 0 or more chars from the defined ranges
- `(?:` - start of an *optional* non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 sequences of

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[a-zA-Z\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]*` - 0 or more chars from the defined ranges
- `)?` - end of the non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string